# TDD on client-server application

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, client-server, protocols, network-protocols

Currently I'm creating a server application to receive protocol-specific messages. I need to create tests to ensure that I've implemented the protocol correctly. Is this some kind of integration testing? If positive, can I make an integration testing with unit testing tools? And finally, what is the best way to create these kind of tests?

Comment: TDD and integration testing are not the same thing. If you are crossing process boundaries (which is very likely in this case), then yes, it is an integration test, not a unit test.

Comment: I've found this link and it confirms what you just said: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development#Fakes.2C_mocks_and_integration_tests

"These tests are quite separate from the TDD unit tests, and are really integration tests. (...) They can nonetheless be implemented using the same testing framework, such as xUnit."

Comment: I would not get hung up on nomenclature.  Just do the testing you think is necessary.  Units, TDD, integration, who cares.  Just make the tests.

Answer (score 5):

If you know what the correct responses are, then here's what I'd do:

Separate the class responsible for the logic of handling the protocol from the code dealing with the mechanics of the connection.

Write tests, one at a time, specifying the correct response for a given set of input messages.

Implement those behaviors.

For instance, if a "hello" message is supposed to be responded to with a "howdy" message, your test might look something like this:

```
Mock<IProtocolOut> outbound = new Mock<IProtocolOut>();
MyProtocolHandler handler = new MyProtocolHandler(outbound); // assuming that the handler takes the outbound receiver as a parameter.
outbound.Expect(o=>o.HowdyMessage()); // we expect to get a HowdyMessage back
handler.HelloMessage(); // 'fake' a HelloMessage into the handler
outbound.VerifyAll(); // assert that the 'howdy' message was sent.
```

All the mock does in this case is assert that certain calls were made.  This can be done by hand-rolling classes to do the verification as well - there's nothing magic about mocks, they just make it easier to do this type of verification.

If you have a mock library that supports Arrange/Act/Assert, it'd look something more like this:

```
Mock<IProtocolOut> outbound = new Mock<IProtocolOut>();
MyProtocolHandler handler = new MyProtocolHandler(outbound); // assuming that the handler takes the outbound receiver as a parameter.
handler.HelloMessage(); // fake the message being sent
outbound.AssertWasCalled(o=>o.HowdyMessage());
```

The interfaces for the protocols don't have to be strongly typed with the messages, of course.  You could also do something similar to this:

```
Mock<IProtocolOut> outbound = new Mock<IProtocolOut>();
MyProtocolHandler handler = new MyProtocolHandler(outbound); // assuming that the handler takes the outbound receiver as a parameter.
handler..ReceiveMessage("hello"); // fake the message being sent
outbound.AssertWasCalled(o=>o.ReceiveMessage("howdy"));
```

(edit for clarification of test scope)

None of these require an 'actual' connection.  They test the *logical* aspects of handling the protocol only, and presume that you have a split between the logical protocol handling, and the connection management.

Comment: Would you consider answering [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43309227/2241463) please?